# How can I insert data using EntityFramework ?

Tags: entity-framework

How can I insert data into my database using `Entity Framework` ?

I'm trying this code bellow, but, in the method `AddObject` I have to pass 2 parameter:

- string entitySetName
- object entity

What is the `entitySetName` ? 
The `object entity` is my model ?

`EntityNetimoveis.San2011Entities db = new EntityNetimoveis.San2011Entities();`
`Model.Gerenciar.UsuarioCurso us = new Model.Gerenciar.UsuarioCurso();`

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
try
    {
        us.Usuario_Id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["id"]);
        db.San_UsuarioCurso.Context.AddObject(us);
        db.SaveChanges();
        context.Response.Write("ok");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        context.Response.Write("");            
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the name of your ObjectSet, in your case `San_UsuarioCurso`.

You're going back and forth in your references however.

In  `db.San_UsuarioCurso.Context.` You're referencing your context (db) and then going to your objectset (San_UsuarioCurso) and then going **back** to your context (Context).

You can add directly to the object set like this, and not have to define the name of the entity set:

```
db.San_UsuarioCurso.AddObject(us);
```

Or if you want to use your function this should work as well:

```
db.San_UsuarioCurso.Context.AddObject("San_UsuarioCurso", us)
```

Comment: I tryied put `db.San_UsuarioCurso.AddObject` but the method `AddObject` don't exist. I can call this method just when I put the `Context`